# How do I multiply two big numbers if their digits are stored in two different arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, product, multiplication

I got a hint that it's possible to multiply them by the standard multiplication method(using 2d arrays). But can anyone please show me how it's done?

Here's my code so far, I couldn't figure out how to handle the carry. I have spent several hours and I just started with coding recently.

```
    int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j;
    printf("Enter multiplicand(n) size: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter multiplier(m) size: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int a[n], b[m];
    printf("Enter multiplicands: ");
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter multipliers: ");
    for(i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }

    int c[m][n+m];
    int k = 0 , l = m+n-1 , p = 2;
    for(i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<m+n; j++)
        {
            c[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(i = m-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(j = n-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            if(a[j]*b[i] < 10)
            {
                c[k][l] = a[j]*b[i] + carry;
                l--;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = a[j]*b[i]%10;
                c[k][l] = carry;
            }
        }
        l = m+n-p;
        p++;
        k++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<m+n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine how you would do it by hand with a pencil and paper.  Now do that in code.

Comment: sorry but I tried and couldn't figure out how to code it.

Comment: in general, your question should focus on a specific problem in YOUR code.  Unfortunately, you have not posted your code.  For this kind of question, suggest posting a [mcve] showing what you have tried and why it is not doing what you want/expect

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it indicates the OP has not put any effort into solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Read wikipedia pages on [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), then read the related conference papers. You can get a PhD in improving multiplication techniques on them. This [report](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/PRL-RR-2.pdf) and [that](https://odr.chalmers.se/bitstream/20.500.12380/253913/1/253913.pdf) one (and many others) should interest you.

Then, **study the source code of some open source bignum library**, such as [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/).

Better yet, just use that library (or some other bignum library, see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software)) from your C program.